# Retrieve the actual value from json

Tags: json, haskell

I have code that parses json:

```
(Aeson.Object jsonObj) -> case (HashMap.lookup "one" jsonObj, HashMap.lookup "two" jsonObj, , HashMap.lookup "three" jsonObj) of
  (Just one, Just two, Just three) -> -- what's next?  
  _ -> error "All three keys don't exist
```

"

How do I  retrieve the actual values from "one", "two" and "three"? All the three are Data.Aeson.Value and its data type is defined as following but yet I can't figure out what to do next:

```
data Value Source

A JSON value represented as a Haskell value.

Constructors
Object !Object   
Array !Array   
String !Text   
Number !Number   
Bool !Bool   
Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the values are of the expected type right in the pattern matching like this:

```
case HashMap.lookup "one" jsonObj of
  (Just (Aeson.String t)) -> -- do with string t what pleases you
  _                       -> error "key not present or not a string"
```

You could adapt this to the triple in your code or leave it as a separate function, whatever you see fit. *But* be aware that this style would really mean that you're not using the `Parser` monad Aeson offers, which is really nice to dissect arbitrary JSON. Assume in your example above, what you really want to achieve is something like this:

```
parseTriple :: ByteString -> Maybe (Text, Integer, Bool)
```

then, using `parseEither`, this can be expressed as simple as

```
parseTriple bs = decode bs >>= parseMaybe $ \o -> do
  one   <- o .: "one"
  two   <- o .: "two"
  three <- o .: "three"
  return (one, two, three)
```

I think this nicely expresses what you're doing with the JSON and is easy to follow and maintain. Also, if you don't use `parseMaybe` but `parseEither`, you even get kind-of-useful error messages for free.